# Flattening nested record in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to flatten the `foo` column in the outer select (in PostgreSQL)?

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT row(d.*) as foo FROM some_multicolumn_table as d
UNION ALL
    SELECT foo FROM t WHERE random() < .5
)
SELECT foo FROM t
```

What I want is to output all the columns (horizontally, i.e. as a row of multiple columns) of `some_multicolumn_table` in the outer select, not just a single "record" column.

How to do that?

Comment: Vertically or horizontally?

Comment: @JakubKania Horizontally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `ROW` constructor there, and so you can expand the record by using `(foo).*`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT d as foo FROM some_multicolumn_table as d
UNION ALL
    SELECT foo FROM t WHERE random() < .5
)
SELECT (foo).* FROM t;
```

Although this query could be simple written as:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT d.* FROM some_multicolumn_table as d
UNION ALL
    SELECT t.* FROM t WHERE random() < .5
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

And I recommend trying to keep it as simple as possible. But I'm assuming it was just an exemplification.